# mysql join count

Tags: mysql

Есть запрос:

```
SELECT topics.*,
       if (topics.expire > '2019-07-02 00:28:03', 1, 0) AS state 
FROM `topics` WHERE `topics`.`deleted_at` IS NULL ORDER BY state DESC LIMIT 20
```

Получаем 20 строк...

Хочу также посчитать количество постов!

Пробовал так:

```
SELECT topics.*,
       (SELECT COUNT(posts_id) WHERE server_id = servers.id) AS posts_count, 
       if (topics.expire > '2019-07-02 00:28:03', 1, 0) AS state 
FROM `topics` 
INNER JOIN `posts` ON `posts`.`topic_id` = `topics`.`id` 
WHERE `topics`.`deleted_at` IS NULL ORDER BY state DESC LIMIT 20
```

Получается только 1 строка...

Пробовал и так:

```
SELECT topics.*,
       COUNT(posts_id) AS posts_count, 
       if (topics.expire > '2019-07-02 00:28:03', 1, 0) AS state 
FROM `topics` 
INNER JOIN `posts` ON `posts`.`topic_id` = `topics`.`id` 
WHERE `topics`.`deleted_at` IS NULL ORDER BY state DESC LIMIT 20
```

Тоже получается 1 строка!

Что не так делаю? Как получить все те же 20 строк + еще count postov по каждому топику?

Comment: добавьте group by в котором укажите до чего группировать (видимо надо перечислить необходимые поля из topic)

Comment: SELECT t.*,
       COUNT(p.posts_id) AS posts_count, 
       if (t.expire > '2019-07-02 00:28:03', 1, 0) AS state 
FROM `topics` t
LEFT JOIN `posts` p ON p.topic_id = t.id 
WHERE t.deleted_at IS NULL GROUP BY t.id ORDER BY state DESC LIMIT 20 а этот код будет работать? Проверьте пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Count подразумевает что будет использоваться функция group_by, поэтому у Вас получается 1 строка. Для того чтобы заработало то, что вы хотите необходимо скорректировать свой запрос:

```
SELECT topics.*, count(posts_id) as posts, 
if(topics.expire > '2019-07-02 00:28:03', 1, 0) AS state 
FROM `topics` 
INNER JOIN `posts` ON `posts`.`topic_id` = `topics`.`id` 
WHERE `topics`.`deleted_at` IS NULL 
GROUP BY topics.id
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: у вас все правильно, кроме ```group by```! Нужно группировать к ```group by topics.id```, а не к posts! Исправьте и я выберу как ответ.

Comment: Исправил. Не правильно понял структуру таблиц